# Google OAuth2 Authentication giving error "Unknown error VerifyAuthentication"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, dotnetopenauth, nopcommerce

I am using FoxNetSoft.ExAuthSocial Plugin for Google OAuth2 External Authentication.
Its redirecting to gmail page properly but after login through gmail login for website is not happening successfully its redirecting to home page with an error "Unknown error VerifyAuthentication"

Comment: have you ask about this to Plugin Author? and can you share you stack trace or error in detail.

Comment: I have only created this custom plugin and simply this error "Unknown error VerifyAuthentication" is showing in login page with unsucessful login after login in google account

Comment: check in nop commerce log there must be detailed error, if not present then notify me, and if there is then put that one....so can guide you

Comment: Having the same problem...